# Is there any way to use $uibModal and $uibModalInstance in a single controller to implement modal popup using angular with typescript?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, popup, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap

As I am a newbie in angular with typescript I am facing a issue while implemented angular modal popup. The issue is I have one drop-down on which change I have to open a modal popup and that modal popup will have two buttons "Yes" or "No". For this I have one controller where I have injected a dependency.

```
export class QuestionnaireController {
    static ngControllerName = 'questionnaireController';
    static inject = ["$uibModal"];
    constructor(private $uibModal: ng.ui.bootstrap.IModalService) {
    }
     public openModalPopup() {
        let options: ng.ui.bootstrap.IModalSettings = {
            controller: QuestionnaireController,
            controllerAs:'ctrl',
            templateUrl: 'app/views/Dialogbox.html',

        };
      this.$uibModal.open(options);

    }
}
```

Most of my code is written in 'QuestionnaireController' and the popup is getting open using this controller but I also want to close this popup so I read a article where it was written that I have to created a new controller "ModalController " to make popup close.

```
export class ModalController {
    static inject = ["$uibModalInstance"];
    constructor(private $uibModalInstance: ng.ui.bootstrap.IModalServiceInstance) {
    }
    public close() {
        this.$uibModalInstance.close();
    }
}
Popup code is here...

<div ng-app="" id="dvModal">
<div class="modal-header">

</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <p> Evaluated result will be discarded if you continue. Are you sure you want to continue?</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <input id="yesBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="ctrl.Yes('true')" value="Yes" />
    <input id="npBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="ctrl.close()" value="No" />
</div>
```

and to close this passed Controller : ModalController in options which makes my popup closed on click of "No". But now the issue is generated here, how I again went to "QuestionnaireController" to do "Yes" functionality as "Yes" functionality is written in QuestionnaireController.

Comment: Check documentation for $uibModal service, it has the answer to your question.

Comment: Can you please suggest the document for the same.

Comment: Here it is: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal Should be enough to solve it.

Comment: We are using typescript so that  $uibModalInstance and $uibModal cant be inject into single controller. Also we have implemented all the code suggested by u but "Yes" button is not getting call as it is in QuestionnaireController.

Comment: @ManishaAgarwal--i have the EXACT same issue!

Comment: @ManishaAgarwal when you do $uibModal.open, it inject's $close, $dismiss to the current scope of QuestionnaireController. So you can just use $scope.$close. I think this should work for you. Thanks

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you can! 
**$uibModal** is super flexible tool.
I'm not super familiar with Typescript, but here's my JS solution:

```
angular
.module('appName', ['ui.bootstrap'])
  .controller('SomePageController', ['$scope', '$uibModal', '$log',
    function ($scope, $uibModal, $log) {
```

First you want to do, is to change your **openModalPopup()** method:

```
    // Instantiate the modal window
    var modalPopup = function () {
      return $scope.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'blocks/modal/dialog.html',
        scope: $scope
      });
    };

    // Modal window popup trigger 
    $scope.openModalPopup = function () {
      modalPopup().result
        .then(function (data) {
          $scope.handleSuccess(data);
        })
        .then(null, function (reason) {
          $scope.handleDismiss(reason);
        });
    };

    // Close the modal if Yes button click
    $scope.yes = function () {
      $scope.modalInstance.close('Yes Button Clicked')
    };

    // Dismiss the modal if No button click
    $scope.no = function () {
      $scope.modalInstance.dismiss('No Button Clicked')
    };

    // Log Success message
    $scope.handleSuccess = function (data) {
      $log.info('Modal closed: ' + data);
    };

    // Log Dismiss message
    $scope.handleDismiss = function (reason) {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed: ' + reason);
    }

  }
]);
```

Second - modal window **HTML template** will look like this:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="blocks/modal/dialog.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      Modal content
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="yes()">Yes</button>
      <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="no()">No</button>
    </div>
  </script>
```

Third - pretty simple **SomePage HTML** (in your case - **Questionnaire**) **View** example :

```
<div ng-controller="SomePageController">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="openModalPopup()">Open modal</button>
</div>
```

#### All together:

```js
angular
  .module('appName', ['ui.bootstrap'])
  .controller('SomePageController', ['$scope', '$uibModal', '$log',
    function($scope, $uibModal, $log) {

      $scope.modalPopup = function() {
        modal = $uibModal.open({
          templateUrl: 'blocks/modal/dialog.html',
          scope: $scope
        });

        $scope.modalInstance = modal;

        return modal.result
      };


      $scope.modalPopupTrigger = function() {
        $scope.modalPopup()
          .then(function(data) {
            $scope.handleSuccess(data);
          },function(reason) {
            $scope.handleDismiss(reason);
          });
      };

      $scope.yes = function() {
        $scope.modalInstance.close('Yes Button Clicked')
      };

      $scope.no = function() {
        $scope.modalInstance.dismiss('No Button Clicked')
      };

      $scope.handleSuccess = function(data) {
        $log.info('Modal closed: ' + data);
      };

      $scope.handleDismiss = function(reason) {
        $log.info('Modal dismissed: ' + reason);
      }

    }
  ]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body ng-app="appName">
  <div ng-controller="SomePageController">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="blocks/modal/dialog.html">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Modal content
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="yes()">Yes</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="no()">No</button>
      </div>
    </script>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="modalPopupTrigger()">Open modal</button>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.7/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular-ui/bootstrap-bower/master/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you pavlo for your answer but this similar way is not completely working with typescript.This $scope.modalInstance in my case it is modalInstance is undefined when using modalInstance.close();

Comment: My guess to this problem is that FEELS like i'm missing a DefinitelyTyped file or something like that...just a hunch though.

Comment: Yes i was also facing the same issue like modalinstance is undefined so i switched to normal bootstrap modal popup and it worked fine, there is no need to add dependency to add in app.module for the same.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you are that lazy guy like me, the following will also work ;)

```
var objects = [{
 name: "obj1",
 value: 1
}, {
 name: "obj2",
 value: 2
}];

// Generating the modal html

var html = "<div class='modal-header'><h4 class='modal-title'>Select Object</h4></div>";
html += "<div class='modal-body'>";
html += "<select class='form-control' ng-model='selection'>";
for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
 var ob = objects[i];
 html += "<option value='" + ob.value + "'>" + ob.name + "</option>";
}
html += "</select>";
html += "</div>";
html += "<div class='modal-footer'>";
html += '<button type="button" ng-click="dismissModal()" class="btn btn-default" >Close</button>';
html += '<button type="button" ng-click="closeModal()" class="btn btn-primary">Select</button>';
html += "</div>";

// Showing the modal

var objectSelectionModal = $uibModal.open({
 template: html,
 controller: function($scope) {

  // The function that is called for modal closing (positive button)

  $scope.closeModal = function() {
   //Closing the model with result
    objectSelectionModal.close($scope.selection);

  };

  //The function that is called for modal dismissal(negative button)

  $scope.dismissModal = function() {
   objectSelectionModal.dismiss();
  };

 }


});

//Processing the Result
objectSelectionModal.result.then(function(selected) {
 alert(selected);

});
```

Comment: you can use ng-templates for this.